# Контекст при передачи функции в другой компонент React

Tags: reactjs, this

У меня возник вопрос по примеру из документации React

[Ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/WZpxpz?editors=0010)

а конкретно по этой строчке кода:

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value);
}
```

Судя по информации из документации, из родительского компонента пробрасывается функция, которая будет храниться в пропе `TemperatureInput` с ключом `onTemperatureChange`. Если посмотреть на значение этой функции, то там будет следующее:

```
this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
```

Получается, что раз мы вызываем эту функцию в `TemperatureInput`, то и `this` должен указывать на `TemperatureInput`, однако он указывает на родительский `Calculator`.

Чем можно объяснить такое поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы пробрасываете функцию из родителя в компонент в качестве prop'a, то ее [контекстом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) будет родитель:

```
const Input = ({ handleChange }) => <input onChange={handleChange} />

const Parent = () => {
   const [state, setState] = useState("")
   
   const handleChange = event => {
      setState(event.target.value)
   }

   return <Input handleChange={handleChange} />
}
```

При использовании классовых компонентов это более очевидно:

```
this.handleChange.bind(this)
```

тут наглядно видно что вместе с функцией так же будет передан контекст.

Comment: спасибо большое! т.е., как я понимаю, это особенность реакта?

Comment: @Pavel нет, Ваш вопрос относиться в большей степени к контексту

Comment: т.е. даже если в ванильном js пробросить подобным образом, то контекст родителя сохранится?

Comment: @Pavel я добавил ссылку в свой ответ касательно `this`. React это просто библиотека, в основе которой все тот же JS